# Is there a way to stop function if text is the same and re-run the function if text isn't the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if the text of a dynamically generated paragraph `<p>` is equal to the previous dynamically generated paragraph, and to stop function if they're (paragraphs) equal and generate another new paragraph that's not equal to the previous.

Something like

```
if(prevParagraph.text() == currentParagraph.text()) {
    stop.function();  // Stop the function and don't generate any paragraph
} else {
    start.function(); // Start the function and generate a non repeated paragraph
}
```

I've tried the following [CODE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQebpN) so far (been trying 5 days now), I can detect it through `console.log();` though, but can't stop it from generating equal text.

Here's a CodePen for that with the complete code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQebpN

The function that generates the text:

```
var checkIfTextIsTheSame;
var createMessage = function(
    cardTitle,
    cardDescription,
    specialOrNot,
    parentHTML
) {
    if (cardDescription == null || cardDescription == undefined) {
        var parentHTML =
            "<div class='container'>" +
            "<div class='parent'><p class='card-title'>" +
            cardTitle +
            "</p></div>" +
            "</div>";
    } else if (specialOrNot != null || specialOrNot != undefined) {
        var parentHTML =
            "<div class='container special'>" +
            "<div class='special-icon-container'> <img src='https://i.imgur.com/0Ae3zdD.png' alt='Special' class='special-icon'></div>" +
            "<div class='parent'><p class='card-title'>" +
            cardTitle +
            "</p>" +
            "<p class='card-description'>" +
            cardDescription +
            "</p></div>" +
            "</div>";
    } else {
        var parentHTML =
            "<div class='container'>" +
            "<div class='parent'><p class='card-title'>" +
            cardTitle +
            "</p>" +
            "<p class='card-description'>" +
            cardDescription +
            "</p></div>" +
            "</div>";
    }

    function createTextAfterCheck() {
        $(".paragraphs-container").append(parentHTML);
        if (
            $(".container")
                .last()
                .text()
                .trim() ==
                $(".container")
                    .last()
                    .prev()
                    .text()
                    .trim() &&
            $(".container").length > 0
        ) {
            checkIfTextIsTheSame = true;
            console.log(checkIfTextIsTheSame);
        } else {
            checkIfTextIsTheSame = false;
            console.log(checkIfTextIsTheSame);
        }
    }
    return createTextAfterCheck();
};

createMessage("test"); // will not be the same because there's no elements before it
createMessage("test");
createMessage("test");
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why don't you use a while loop ?

Comment: an example please? @SyedMehtabHassan

Comment: Where is your code for dynamically generating paragraph?

Comment: Last section in my post, `function createMessage` @SyedMehtabHassan

Comment: But why don't you put **createMessage("test")** in the false branch of **createTextAfterCheck()**? **createMessage()** doesn't check anything only creates an HTML string. You check the condition in **createTextAfterCheck()**. Or is the problem that it evaluates to **true**?

Comment: @muka.gergely I tried that, and it freezes at **true** and it doesn't generates anymore paragraphs. :/

Comment: @Mr-Fox I added a possible solution. Keeping track of messages and giving them IDs is kinda’ best practice - much easier to modify (and compare) them, and your app’s messages will stay consistent even if you rephrase one (if you put them in a central array). Plus you don’t have to worry about HTML markup, only the message text items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered your code a bit:
- simplified the **createMessage()** function, so it's easier to test with,
- added an ID to texts (actually this way you could keep track of all your messages in an `object`, and just pick one from there, when you need it in code

```js
var checkIfTextIsTheSame;

function createMessage(mId, cardTitle, cardDescription, specialOrNot, parentHTML) {
  if (cardDescription == null || cardDescription == undefined) {
    parentHTML =
      "<div class='container' data-mid=" + mId + ">" +
      cardTitle +
      "</div>";
  } else if (specialOrNot != null || specialOrNot != undefined) {
    parentHTML =
      "<div class='container special' data-mid=" + mId + ">" +
      cardTitle +
      cardDescription +
      "</div>";
  } else {
    parentHTML =
      "<div class='container' data-mid=" + mId + ">" +
      cardTitle +
      cardDescription +
      "</div>";
  }

  if (!createTextAfterCheck(mId)) {
    $(".paragraphs-container").append(parentHTML);
  }

}

function createTextAfterCheck(id) {
  let check = false;

  if ($(".container").last().attr("data-mid") == id && $(".container").length > 0) {
    check = true;
  }
  return check;
}

createMessage(0, "test"); // will not be the same because there's no elements before it
createMessage(0, "test");
createMessage(0, "test");

var $form = $("#myForm");
$form.on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formIsValid = false;
  var formIsEmpty = true;

  $("input.email").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
      formIsEmpty = false;
    } else {
      formIsEmpty = true;
    }
    if (
      /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/i.test(
        $(this).val()
      )
    ) {
      formIsValid = true;
    } else {
      formIsValid = false;
    }
  });

  if (formIsEmpty == true) {
    createMessage(1, "This field can't be empty");
  }

  if (formIsEmpty == false && formIsValid == false) {
    createMessage(2, 
      "Oops, there must be an error in the provided email, please enter a valid one"
    );
  }

  if (formIsEmpty == false && formIsValid == true) {
    createMessage(3, "thank you for signing-up", " ", "thanks message");
  }
});
```

```css
.special .special-icon-container,
.special .parent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.special .special-icon {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0 8px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">

  <input type="text" class="email" form="myForm">

  <input type="submit" form="myForm">

</form>

<div class="paragraphs-container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I’m happy that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could store the previous message as a variable, and check against it whenever you are calling createMessage(), something like this:

```
var currentMessage = "";

function createMessage(message) {
    if(message != currentMessage) {
        message = currentMessage;
        //change the message in your paragraph
    }
}
```

EDIT: Or if you don't want to use a variable, you can check against the paragraph's current `innerHTML`, like so (where `#your-paragraph` is the dynamically generated paragraph):

```
function createMessage(message) {
    if(message != $("#your-paragraph").html()) {
        message = currentMessage;
        //change the message in your paragraph
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives always **false**

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified your code (see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MREyba))

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
    function createTextAfterCheck() {
    var currElement = $("<div/>").append(parentHTML);
    var lastElement = $("<div/>").append($(".container").last().clone());

    if (
        $(".container").length > 0 &&
        currElement.html() == lastElement.html()            
    ) {
        checkIfTextIsTheSame = true;
        console.log(checkIfTextIsTheSame);
    } else {
        $('.paragraphs-container').append(currElement.html());
        checkIfTextIsTheSame = false;
        console.log(checkIfTextIsTheSame);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked, but a bit buggy, it returns sometimes **true**, but I didn't understand the `<div/>` part, because I have another HTML code on my page, do you think that it creates conflicts? I hope if it's possible to change `<div/>` to something else with the selectors that I have, thanks.

Comment: The div part just creates a new div element and acts like a wrapper around your actual element. So if you call .html() you are able to compare the inner html of your elements.

Comment: I just changed this
`currElement.html() == lastElement.html()`
into this 
`currElement.text() == lastElement.text()`
and it works perfectly now, thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear. I‘d recommend to console.log() so you check the output.